# No suitable conversion function from "const std::string" to "time_t" exists

Tags: c++, boost

I'm doing a conversion from epoch time to proper date and time. So far I found out that boost library could help me with this. However, I got the error **No suitable conversion function from "const std::string" to "time_t" exists**

```
    const std::string timeparser(jsonData["data"]["table"][i]["data"]["created_utc"].asString());
```

timeparser may consist of "1522516475"

```
    std::time_t btime_ = timeparser;

    std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_) << endl;
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%H:%M:%S")));
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_) << endl;
```

Comment: Why do you think you could convert whatever value is in the string to a `time_t`? And what *is* the contents of `timeparser`?

Comment: the content may include something like "1522516522"

Comment: And what *unit* is that number? Is it a POSIX time-stamp? The number of seconds since the epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
std::time_t btime_ = timeparser;
```

Because the left hand type is a number, and the right hand is a string.  You need to convert:

```
std::time_t btime_ = std::stoi(timeparser);
```